# Getting invalid JSON on API call

Tags: javascript, json, api, express

I'm trying to use GoToMeeting's API and making a POST request to create a meeting. At the moment, I'm just trying to hardcode the body of the meeting and send headers but I'm receiving and I'm invalid JSON error and not sure why. Here's the code for that route:

```
app.post('/new-meeting', (req, res) => {

  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application / json',
    Authorization: 'OAuth oauth_token=' + originalToken
  };

  console.log('-----------------------------------------------------------')
  console.log('Acess Token:');
  console.log('OAuth oauth_token=' + originalToken);
  console.log('-----------------------------------------------------------')

  const meetingBody = {
    subject: 'string',
    starttime: '2018-03-20T08:15:30-05:00',
    endtime: '2018-03-20T09:15:30-05:00',
    passwordrequired: true,
    conferencecallinfo: 'string',
    timezonekey: 'string',
    meetingtype: 'immediate'
  };

  return fetch('https://api.getgo.com/G2M/rest/meetings', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: meetingBody,
    headers: headers
  }).then(response => {

    console.log('response:');
    console.log(response);


    response
      .json()
      .then(json => {
        res.send(json);
        console.log(req.headers);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
});
```

When I hit that router, I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "resource": "/rest/meetings",
    "message": "invalid json"
  }
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify()` your `meetingBody` object before putting into the `body` option, I do not think `fetch` automatically parses objects to json

Comment: @PatrickEvans stringifying the body means the header needs to be changed, plus the api most likely accepts json in the body

Comment: @mast3rd3mon, no it doesn't. The header just tells the server what to expect, and since JSON is text and stringifying an object results in text the header does not need changed

Comment: stringifying json turns it into text so the header becomes text/plain

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — No, it doesn't. `JSON.stringify` outputs a **JSON text**. JSON text is not *plain* text.

Comment: yes, it does, or atleast it then doesnt send as json but instead a json string

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — No. We've had this conversation before. You still don't seem to understand the difference between the JSON data format and JavaScript literal syntax. (Or the difference between *A JavaScript string containing JSON* and *A string expressed in the JSON data format*)

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — Read http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: i have, and its rubbish, not to mention old. our work servers expect json and i pass a json object, both node servers that i have made also expect json and i pass json objects into them as well

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — It is not rubbish. It is old, but that's because JSON is old and people have been making your mistake for a long time. I'm not going to try to understand what your work servers are doing because I don't have access to them. It probably comes down to other people you know making the same mistake and writing down incorrect documentation because of it.

Comment: yes it is rubbish, and our work servers expect json so i send json objects, if i send json strings, i will get errors as its invalid

Comment: There is no such thing as json objects. If you are passing an object then somewhere in the internals of whatever you are using transforms it into JSON and then sends it. So if you stringify it before hand it probably ends up as if `JSON.stringify( JSON.stringify() )` was done hence why you would probably get an error.

Comment: JSON objects are just standard JSON, atleast thats what i mean by it. ie `{"propName": "ValueHere"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

You are passing `fetch` a value for the `body` represented by a JavaScript object. It is converting it to a string by (implicitly) calling its `.toString()` method. This doesn't give you JSON. The API you are calling then complains and tells you that it isn't JSON.

You need to convert your object to JSON using:

```
body: JSON.stringify(meetingBody),
```

---

## Test case

This demonstrates the problem and the solution.

### Server

This is designed to be a very primitive and incomplete mock of GoToMeeting's API. It just echos back the request body.

```
const express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: "*/*" }));

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(req.body)
});

app.listen(7070, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 7070!'))
```

### Client

This represents your code, but with the Express server stripped out. Only the code relevant for sending the request to GoToMeeting's API is preserved.

```
const url = "http://localhost:7070/";
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application / json',
    Authorization: 'OAuth oauth_token=foobarbaz'
};

const meetingBody = {
    subject: 'string',
    starttime: '2018-03-20T08:15:30-05:00',
    endtime: '2018-03-20T09:15:30-05:00',
    passwordrequired: true,
    conferencecallinfo: 'string',
    timezonekey: 'string',
    meetingtype: 'immediate'
};


fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: meetingBody,
        headers: headers
    })
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => console.log(body));
```

### Results of running the test case

The logs of both server and client show:

```
[object Object]
```

This is what you get when you call `meetingBody.toString()`.

If you change the code as described at the top of this answer, you get:

```
{"subject":"string","starttime":"2018-03-20T08:15:30-05:00","endtime":"2018-03-20T09:15:30-05:00","passwordrequired":true,"conferencecallinfo":"string","timezonekey":"string","meetingtype":"immediate"}
```

This is JSON, which is what the API is expecting.

---

## Aside

MIME types do not have spaces in them. `Accept: 'application / json',` should be `Accept: 'application/json',`. This *probably* isn't causing you any problems though.

Comment: THANK YOU QUENTIN. THAT WORKED!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the header is incorrect.

You need 'Accept: application/json' without space.

Comment: and `Accept` and `Authorization` need quoting

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — They are valid identifier names. They **do not** need quoting.

Comment: yet the `Content-Type` is quoted

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — It has a `-` in it. It is not a valid identifier name. In an object literal it must therefore be represented as a string.

Comment: yes, it is valid... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — You seem to be confused. We're talking about the property names in an object literal in JavaScript syntax. While those property names represent HTTP headers, the rules for HTTP headers tell us nothing about what is valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: It will still work without quoting: `{hello: 'world', 'this': 'works'}`

Comment: The `-` will not make it valid. Content-Type needs to be in quotations. I did overlook the `application/json` line though.

Unfortunately, I'm still getting a `Unexpected token J in JSON at position 0'` error. So there's a syntax error somewhere.